# Listing Common files from multiple project base directories

Tags: c++, boost, stl, multimap

Hello All,
               I have been handled a task to which I am very new. Task description is detailed below.

Listing Common files(especially .c and .cpp) from multiple project base directories based on below requirements :-

1. Must use some STL container (E.g. Multimap) and object oriented design.
2. Should be portable to be used on Linux and Windows and must be single threaded.
3. In advance search it should also look for similarities of contents of the file.
4. Should be extendable to search in multiple base project directories
5. Must be efficient to work with thousands of files.

Explanation of Point 4 :- Should be extendable to search in multiple base project directories
User may provide 3 base directories path say A, B, C. We need to scan all these three directories till last level and find out common files. File may be common between only two directories say A and B but that's fine. If file is present in more than one project then it must be listed.

While doing some research on this I came across boost::filesystem which is portable. So any input in this direction are welcome.

Comment: What is your design?

Comment: You gotta ask a specific question on stack overflow, not a general request for input....

Comment: Is this a dressed-up homework assignment to do a poor-man's plagiarism detector?

Comment: @Thomas :- I can design it my way as far as it satisfies above stated conditions. Consider it as a standalone application.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams : I tried to be as specific as I can by stating all conditions that I have to cope up with. As told earlier I am not a expert in OOPS.

Comment: In other words, what have you designed so far?